# Wordpress Login automation

Tags: java, wordpress, selenium

I am trying to automate login process on [www.wordpress.com](http://www.wordpress.com)

- Step1: Click on "Login" button on top right corner.
- Step2: Click on "Continue with Google" on the Login page.

But I can only perform Step1. When I automate to click on "Continue with Google", it just doesn't click.

What happens is the cursor keeps blinking on "Email Address or Username" field. It just doesn't click on anything else. Same if I try to automate. Is it some iframe issue? Please help

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TestAddNewPost {

    String baseUrl = "https://wordpress.com/";
    public void LoginIntoWordpress(){

        // System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/ashwin/Desktop/chromedriver");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/ashwin/Desktop/geckodriver");
        // WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(baseUrl);

        WebElement LoginButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='x-nav-link x-link']     [contains(text(),'Log In')]"));
        LoginButton.click();

        WebElement continueWithGoogle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Continue with Google')]"));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        continueWithGoogle.click();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        TestAddNewPost object = new TestAddNewPost();
        object.LoginIntoWordpress();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You just need to provide more waiting time before clicking on the 'Continue with Googlebutton**

```
 driver.get("https://www.wordpress.com");   
 WebElement LoginButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='x-nav-link 
                                xlink'[contains(text(),'LogIn')]"));
 LoginButton.click();
 driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.wordpress.com");
    WebElement LoginButton = driver
            .findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='x-nav-link x-link'][contains(text(),'Log In')]"));
    LoginButton.click();
   Thread.sleep(5000);
    WebElement continueWithGoogle = 
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Continue with Google')]"));
              
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000); 
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    continueWithGoogle.click();
}

Hope the above code solves you issue
```